# How to mock useState hook and check if setState have been called with vitest?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mocking, vitest

I'm migrating from jest to vitest at my React application.

I'm testing a component which must call the setState function in certain situations and with jest I did something like:

```js
    it('Component should call setState on render', () => {
        const setState = jest.fn();

        jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockReturnValue(['', setState]);

        render(<Component />);

        expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith('text');
    });
```

However, when using vitest - and properly changing 'jest.' for 'vi.' - this test does no work and I receive the following message:

```bash
 FAIL  src/__tests__/components/Component.spec.tsx > Component > Component should call setState on render
AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called with arguments: [ 'text' ]expected "spy" to be called with arguments: [ 'text' ]

Received:


Number of calls: 0

 ❯ src/__tests__/components/Component.spec.tsx:82:19
     80|   );
     81|
     82|   expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith('text');
       |                   ^
     83|  });
     84|
```

How this implementation should be made with vitest? Its mocking function appears to works differently from jest.

Comment: Don't mock it, you will break its function. Don't test implementation detail, test the behavior.